# Unable to save Relationship property values in Spring data Neo4j 3.1

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a simple usage case where I have n store --> which has k number of products. I want to connect the store with a relationship HasProduct. On that realationship I want to capture product qty, price because of each store the qty and price will be different.

```
@Data
@Node
public class Store {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Property
    private String businessType;
    @Property
    private int currentOnhandInventory;
    @Property
    private String locationId;
    @Property
    @Relationship(type = "HasProduct", value = "HasProduct", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private List<Product> topSellingProducts;
}

@Data
@Node
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Property
    private String name;
    @Property
    private String description;
    @Property
    private String department;
    @Property
    @Relationship
    private Store store;

}

@Data
@RelationshipProperties
public class HasProduct {

    @RelationshipId
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Property
    private String qty;

    @Property
    private Double price;

    @TargetNode
    private Product product;

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/store")
public class StoreController {

    private StoreRepository storeRepository;
    
    public StoreController(StoreRepository storeRepository) {
        this.storeRepository = storeRepository;
    }

    @PutMapping
    Mono<Store> createOrUpdateStore(@RequestBody Store newStore) {
        return storeRepository.save(newStore);
    }

    @GetMapping
    Mono<Store> getStoreById(@RequestParam Long id) {
        return storeRepository.findById(id);
    }
}

@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class Config {

    
    @Bean(ReactiveNeo4jRepositoryConfigurationExtension.DEFAULT_TRANSACTION_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME)
    public ReactiveTransactionManager reactiveTransactionManager(
        Driver driver,
        ReactiveDatabaseSelectionProvider databaseNameProvider) {
        return new ReactiveNeo4jTransactionManager(driver, databaseNameProvider);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Configuration cypherDslConfiguration() {
        return Configuration.newConfig()
            .withDialect(Dialect.NEO4J_5)
            .build();
    } 
}

public interface StoreRepository extends ReactiveNeo4jRepository<Store, Long> {
    Mono<List<Store>> findOneById(Long id);
}
```

When I am trying to save a store object I am getting this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "valueToCheck" is null
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.mapping.NestedRelationshipProcessingStateMachine.hasProcessedValue(NestedRelationshipProcessingStateMachine.java:178) ~[spring-data-neo4j-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Flux.checkpoint(Flux.java:3454)
    org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.ReactiveNeo4jTemplate.processNestedRelations(ReactiveNeo4jTemplate.java:1049)
```

Can somebody help with this, as there are not much documentation or examples are available for Spring data 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

You should need to map the relationship properties class by putting that in your domain class. I like to think of the relationship properties class as a separate entity where you need to chain a node to a relationship to a node. So, in the Store class, you need something like this:

```
@Relationship("HasProduct")
private List<HasProduct> topSellingProducts;
```

Couple small examples:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.annotations.relationship.properties
- https://github.com/JMHReif/neo4j-code-wars/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jmhreif/neo4jcodewars/Order.java